# Fixed “moved” volume on Mac terminal

Tags: hard-drive, mac, mount

I tried renaming my external hard drive.  I incorrectly used the terminal command `sudo mv /Volume/oldname /Volume/newname` command instead of the proper command `/usr/sbin/diskutil rename oldname newname`

Now my Mac is unable to read the external hard drive.  Any tips for making the hard drive readable again?  Here is the output of `ls -la /Volumes`.  You can see that the permissions are incorrect.

```
drwxr-xr-x   5 root    wheel     160 Jul  8 08:59 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root    wheel     736 Nov 10  2020 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    wheel       1 Jun 24 09:26 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxrwxrwx   1 myname  staff  262144 Dec 31  1979 external_drive
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel      96 Nov 10  2020 Recovery
```

Trying to remount it does not fix the issue:

```
sudo diskutil mount readOnly /Volumes/external_drive

sudo: setrlimit(RLIMIT_FSIZE): Invalid argument
Volume on (null) failed to mount
If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

Comment: For next time, click on the drive in Finder, hit Enter/Return & type a new name. Much harder to make a mess of it. BTW, the `mv` conmmand should have just failed, as there would have been no volume called `new name`… this makes me think that's not exactly what you did.

Comment: @Tetsujin just checked my shell history and yes I did `sudo mv /Volume/oldname /Volume/newname`.  Yeah, I should have just renamed it using Finder.

Comment: well, the mount point should have been /Volumes not /Volume, so I've not a clue what actually may have happened. It should have just errored as your command was essentially garbage.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct the mount is `/Volumes/`

Comment: It should still have errored, as it had nowhere to move to.